# Not able to resolve Maven dependencies in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, intellij-15

I am working on a project using Maven dependencies. But, I am not able to get it resolved in IntelliJ or in other words, IntelliJ shows red in import. Is there any extra configuration required?

Below is how my IntelliJ Maven configuration looks like -

[image]
[image]
[image]

In command line, Maven version I see is -

> WFORealtimePassThroughLambda % mvn --version
> **Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)** Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec Java version:
> 18.0.2.1, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.2.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
> Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "mac os x",
> version: "12.5.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Answer (score 1):

None of the solution available on internet worked for me. Finally, I had to delete the workspace and created it again. In IntelliJ, on opening for the first time, it was prompting "Download pre-built shared indexes" at right bottom corner, I clicked on it, which seem to download all Maven dependencies. After that, all dependencies got resolved.